# Unable to read version 4 table /var/www/html/magento217/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/Font.php(615)

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I have a problem in Arabic characters in invoice pdf print(they are separated and reversed).

I am trying to use the Noto fonts https://www.google.com/get/noto/

but I got this error:

> a:4:{i:0;s:30:"Unable to read version 4 table";i:1;s:5227:"#0
> /var/www/html/magento217/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/Font.php(615):
> Zend_Pdf_Font::_extractTrueTypeFont(Object(Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File),
> 0)
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/magento217/app/code/Rossmc/SalesPdfFonts/Model/Order/Pdf/SetFontTrait.php(43):
>
> Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/var/www/html/m...')

Can any body help ..

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue with the Zend Framework. Basically the OS/2 version of the font you are using is not supported. You could try using a different font or converting the current one somehow. Other then that i don't see a solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094822/zend-framework-with-handwritten-font